# Убрать атрибут обязательное заполнение поля при выполнении условия

Tags: javascript

Как сделать так, чтобы в коде JS ниже сделать поля `input` необязательными к заполнению внутри `if` ? Я понимаю, что `required` - `boolean`, но запихнуть `required` = `false` внутри `if` не выходит.

```
document.querySelector("[name=prevdocid]")
    .addEventListener("change", function (e) {       
        const input  = document.querySelector('[name="doc_series"]');
        const input2 = document.querySelector('[name="doc_number"]');
        const input3 = document.querySelector('[name="doc_date"]');

        input.disabled = !["1","2", "3", "4","5","6","7","8"].includes(this.value);

        if (input.disabled) {
            input.value = "";
        }
        input2.disabled = !["1","2", "3", "4","5","6","7","8"].includes(this.value);
        if (input2.disabled) {
            input2.value = "";
        }
        input3.disabled = !["1","2", "3", "4","5","6","7","8"].includes(this.value);
        if (input3.disabled) {
            input3.value = "";
        }
});
```

Comment: `disabled` вы ставите, почему бы `required` таким же образом не установить?

Comment: Пробовал, вышло не очень

Comment: так покажите, как пробовали

Comment: Самый верный был при использовании input.required = true. Там хотя бы появлялся атрибут обязательного заполнения в коде, но не функционировал по прямому назначению. Работаю внутри сервлета

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>HTML5</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<input class="input" required disabled type="text">
<button class="enableBtn">enable</button>
<script>
    const btn=document.querySelector('.enableBtn');
    btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        input=document.querySelector('.input');
        if (input.disabled) {
            input.removeAttribute('required');
            input.removeAttribute('disabled');
        }
    });
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Не работает, к сожалению